# Observing timeout exception when client connects to WCF service - both residing in same application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a app which is hosting a WCF service. Some info:

- It has to be a singleton app - means that not another instance of it can run parallelly. For now, assume the below sample form app has been designed so.
- It needs to act as a client too.
- It uses net.tcp binding
- It uses SecurityMode = Transport

But when I invoke method from client, the server doesn't get the invocation. I see a "Timeout exception" when "CallServer" method is invoked.

Please, if you suggest to change settings of `InstanceContextMode` or `ConcurrencyMode` or `SessionMode`, try it yourself first, because I have tried the combinations and they did not help.

The code here is a sample, but can be used to test. To use this code, create 2 buttons: btnHostService and btnClientInvoke on the form.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        ServiceHost _host;
        const string URI = "net.tcp://localhost:8602/MyService";

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += delegate { if (_host != null) _host.Close(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)); };
        }

        private void btnHostService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //don't host again
            if (_host != null) return;

            _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ContractServer), new Uri(URI));

            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport) { PortSharingEnabled = true };
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContract), binding, string.Empty);
            _host.Opened += delegate { MessageBox.Show(this, "Service Hosted"); };
            _host.Open();
        }

        private void btnClientInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport) { PortSharingEnabled = true };
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            ////set all of them to 1 min - which is default
            //binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            //binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            //binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

            ContractClient client = null;
            try {
                client = new ContractClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(URI));
                client.CallServer();
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
            }

            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exc) {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
                    client.Abort();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
            if (_host != null)
                _host.Close(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    public interface IContract {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void CallServer();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class ContractServer : IContract {
        public void CallServer() {
            MessageBox.Show("Client called!");
        }
    }
    public class ContractClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IContract>, IContract {
        public ContractClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : base(binding, remoteAddress) { }

        public void CallServer() {
            base.Channel.CallServer();
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 1

For info: fix is to use "UseSynchronizationContext = false" in `ContractServer` and disable portsharing in the host binding. But I don't know why.

Comment: In your real code you also host the service in a WinForms app?

Comment: Yes, it is winform app, of complicated nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a deadlock.

When you host a `WCF` service in an application it uses that application's synchronization context. In this case, a `WinForms` app, a single threaded synchronization context.

So when your "client" calls your "server" it gets blocked until it gets a response and the "server" can't send that response because the single thread is blocked by the "client", hence deadlock.

To fix that you need to tell the service to not use that synchronization context:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    UseSynchronizationContext = false,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class ContractServer : IContract 
{
    public void CallServer() 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Client called!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but it did not work. But the theory might be right. Just the proposed solution is not working.

Comment: @Nayan It does work without the port sharing. why are you using port sharing?

Comment: Okay! That worked!! I was using it because I do not want to block the port. But, can you explain what happened by disabling port sharing?

Comment: @Nayan I don't really know. I think the port sharing service can't find the right listener, but i don't really know why.